# Imacros Regex - Isolate name and surname

Tags: regex, string, trim, imacros

I am struggling for quite a while now.
I am extracting text from a Website using Imacros with this result :

> 

```
                    Niklaus Hasling
```

There are whitespaces before the first name and after the surname
This String is stored in the variable !VAR2

I would like to use a regex that isolates the first name in !VAR3 and the surname in !VAR4

Can someone help me ?

I can't figure out how to write the regex

```html
'Extract and Save Names
TAG XPATH="/html/body/main/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/dl/dt/span" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.trim(REGEX'')")
SET !VAR3 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL

'Extract and save SurNames
TAG XPATH="/html/body/main/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/dl/dt/span" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.trim(REGEX'')")
SET !VAR4 {{!EXTRACT}}
SET !EXTRACT NULL
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XO8l.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this could trim the white spaces before and after the names :

^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$.

and an array could split names, but I cant figure out how with iMacros

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67472395/edit) your question to add this information, not post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, you seem to like `XPATH` and `REGEX`, ah-ah...!

Implementation without `REGEX` (that I don't like and never use):

```scala
'Extract and Save First (`!VAR3`) + Last (`!VAR4`) Names:
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG XPATH="/html/body/main/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/dl/dt/span" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !VAR3 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var x,y,z; x=s.trim(); y=x.split(' '); z=y[0]; z;")
SET !VAR4 EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var x,y,z; x=s.trim(); y=x.split(' '); z=y[1]; z;")
'>
'Debug:
SET Debug_Info EXTRACT:<BR>_{{!EXTRACT}}_<BR><BR>
ADD Debug_Info First_Name:<SP>_{{!VAR3}}_<BR>Last_Name:<SP>_{{!VAR4}}_
PROMPT {{Debug_Info}}
```

`!ERRORIGNORE` is "needed" in case `y[1]` does not "exist", or iMacros will throw a Runtime Error...

Comment: [Sarcastic Mode=ON]And the Follow-up by @OP is very "impressive", 2 days later...! ... And still nothing...[Sarcastic-Mode=OFF]